# Error setting spatial dimensions in netCDF file

Tags: python, gis, geospatial, raster, netcdf

I'm trying to convert a NetCDF file to raster using rioxarray in python. However, when I try to set lat and lon as spatial dimensions (they are variables in my original .nc file), I get an error message.

How can I set lon and lat from variables to dimensions? Is there an alternative way to convert a NetCDF file to raster? Thanks!

Here is my full code:

```
import xarray as xr 
import rioxarray as rio 

nc_file = xr.open_dataset('......') #path to nc data file 
nc_file = nc_file.set_spatial_dims(x_dim='nav_lon', y_dim='nav_lat') #set spatial dimensions
bT = nc_file['votemper'] #extract variable from nc data
bT.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True) #define CRS
bT.rio.to_raster(r"bottomT_raster.tiff") #save as raster
```

Here is the structure of my nc_file:

```
nc_file
Out[60]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:       (y: 86, x: 102, deptht: 1, time_counter: 132)
Coordinates:
  * deptht        (deptht) float32 3.047
  * time_counter  (time_counter) datetime64[ns] 2009-01-16T12:00:00 ... 2019-...
Dimensions without coordinates: y, x
Data variables:
    nav_lon       (y, x) float32 -26.05 -26.0 -25.95 ... -21.1 -21.05 -21.0
    nav_lat       (y, x) float32 13.96 13.96 13.96 13.96 ... 18.04 18.04 18.04
    votemper      (time_counter, y, x) float32 ...
    vosaline      (time_counter, y, x) float32 ...
```

And here is the error when setting the spatial dimensions:

```
nc_file = nc_file.set_spatial_dims(x_dim='nav_lon', y_dim='nav_lat')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/var/folders/fy/wyzk01_n36jgjq0csnn195080000gn/T/ipykernel_1587/4107632915.py", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    nc_file = nc_file.set_spatial_dims(x_dim='nav_lon', y_dim='nav_lat')

  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/common.py", line 239, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(

AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'set_spatial_dims'
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused because when you read the file a type [`Dataset`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.html#xarray-dataset) object is returned, so which does not contain any method called `set_spatial_dimentions`, what you could do is, convert it to an **`array`** type object using function [`to_array`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.to_array.html#xarray-dataset-to-array) and then use the `set_spatial_dimen` method:

```
nc_file = xr.open_dataset('......')
nc_file = nc_file.to_array()
nc_file = nc_file.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)
```

and
`nc_file.rio.set_spatial_dims("nav_lon", "nav_lat", inplace=True)`

related topics:

- [setting dimension using rioxarray set_spatial_dims()](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403860/problem-in-setting-dimension-using-rioxarray-set-spatial-dims)
- [converting NetCDF dataset with 2D coordinates to GeoTiff #47](https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/issues/47)